# Show that the sequence $a_n=\frac{\sin(n)}{2+\cos(n)}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis

So I know that I want to use the Bolzano-Weierstrauss Theorem here. I know that $\sin(n)$ is bounded by $-1 \leq \sin(n) \leq 1$ and that $2+\cos(n)$ is bounded by $1 \leq 2+\cos(n) \leq 3$. But then when I try to divide to get the bounds for $a_n$ I get $-1 \leq a_n \leq \frac{1}{3}$ which the upper bound is not correct there. How do I get the correct upper bound for $a_n$? Thanks!

Comment: To make $U_n/V_n$ as large as possible (when they are positive), make $U_n$ as large as possible, and make $V_n$ as small as possible.

Comment: @GEdgar So that would mean my upper bound should be 1?

Answer (score 2):

See this

> $$ |2+\cos n|  \geq 2 - |\cos n | \geq 2 - 1 =1 \implies \frac{1}{|2+\cos n|} \leq 1 $$

together with the inequality $|\sin n| \leq 1 $ gives the inequality

> $$ \frac{|\sin n|}{|2+\cos n|} \leq 1 . $$

Comment: Oh man I forgot I had $\frac{1}{2+\cos(n)}$!

Comment: @mconn7: We all forget and miss things! Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Simple differential calculus shows that for all real $x$,
$$
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \leq \frac{\sin x}{2 + \cos x} \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$
(the upper and lower bounds are hit at $x = \frac{(6k+2)\pi}{3}$ and $x = \frac{(6k+4)\pi}{3}$ for integer $k$, respectively).

Since this holds for all real $x$ it holds in particular for integer $n$, so the bounds you can use in BW are 
$$
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \leq \frac{\sin n}{2 + \cos n} \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$
$$
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \leq a_n \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Such a sequence is trivially bounded, for instance by Chappers' bound.

The thing it is interesting to notice is that we don't even need the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. Since $\pi$ is an irrational number, the sequence given by $a_n=e^{in}$ is dense in the unit circle, hence for any $(x,y)\in S^1$ we can find a subsequence of the original sequence converging to:
$$ \frac{y}{2+x}, $$
i.e. to any number in the range $\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos{n} \geqslant-1$, so the smallest the denominator can be is $1$. The thing is that the sine and cosine can have different signs, so the best you can say is
$$ \left\lvert \frac{\sin{n}}{2+\cos{n}} \right\rvert \leqslant \lvert \sin{n} \rvert \leqslant 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

The exact value of the limits wouldn't matter if you just want to prove the sequence has a convergent subsequence.
OTOH, the upper limit of $\sin n/(1+\cos n)$ is likely equal to the maximum of $\sin x/(1+\cos x)$, which you can find by differentiating it.  That is because $n$ can get as close to $\theta+2m\pi$ as you like, for any $\theta$.

Comment: Right, and that will be $1/\sqrt 3.$ In fact the set of subsequential limits of $(\sin n)/(2+\cos n)$ will be $[-1/\sqrt 3,1/\sqrt 3].$